# NIO: What exactly does it mean that a SelectionKey is ready?

Tags: selector, nio

I was wondering if there is some definitive answer to what it means for a SelectionKey (really its Channel) to be 'ready' for a specific type of event?

key.isAcceptable): does it mean that a client has established a connection (sent a SYN and the server has issued a SYN + ACK)?; I believe that is the case since simply binding a ServerSocketChannel doesn't make it 'acceptable' (verified this in tests)

key.isReadable():  does it mean that the socket's receive buffer is not full (which of course includes empty)? or does it mean that there are unread bytes in its receive-buffer? (I'm presuming it's the first since channel.read() can equal 0 even when key.isReadable()) - but then again surely a 'dormant' channel (one that is open but in which the client is not sending data) is not repeatedly returned in the selector's selected-keyset?

I'm guessing the answer is 'implementation-dependent'

Answer (score 0):

> key.isAcceptable): does it mean that a client has established a connection (sent a SYN and the server has issued a SYN + ACK)?;

It means that *at least one* client has done that. Maybe more. All such clients will be sitting in the backlog queue.

> key.isReadable(): does it mean that the socket's receive buffer is not full (which of course includes empty)?

No.

> or does it mean that there are unread bytes in its receive-buffer?

It means there is data in the socket receive buffer. When you read it it is removed, so all data there is 'unread'.

> (I'm presuming it's the first since channel.read() can equal 0 even when key.isReadable())

No it can't.

> but then again surely a 'dormant' channel (one that is open but in which the client is not sending data) is not repeatedly returned in the selector's selected-keyset?

Of course not. Only channels that have data ready to read.

You didn't ask, but:

- `isWritable()`: means there is *room* in the socket send buffer. This is almost always the case, which is why you should only register `OP_WRITE` when it is definitely known that it isn't the case, i.e. after a `write()` returns zero, and it should be deregistered immediately a `write()` has succeeded without returning zero.
- `isConnectable()`: means that you called `connect()` in non-blocking mode with `OP_CONNECT` registered, and you should now call `finishConnect()`, and if it returns `true` you should deregister `OP_CONNECT` and, probably, write your first request, as you are a  client.

Comment: Are you certain that channel.read() *never* returns 0 when key.isReadable()?  It seems at least possible that selector.select() is subject to _spurious selects_